# Show $r(F)=r(F^2)$ implies $Im(F) \cap Ker(F)=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I wonder if I've made some mistakes in the proof of the following or if there is some simpler solution.

**Problem:** Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vectorspace and $F:V \rightarrow V$ a linear operator. Show that $rank(F^2)=rank(F)$ implies $Im(F) \cap Ker(F)= \{0\}$.

**My solution:** I work with the matrix instead of the mapping, denote the matrix as $F$ too. Assume $\dim(V)=n$, and then $F$ is a square matrix of size $n$. $$Im(F)=\{FX : X \in \mathbb{K^n} \}$$ $$Ker(F)=\{X \in \mathbb{K^n} : FX=0\} $$

Assume there exist $v \in Im(F) \cap Ker(F)$ and $v \not=0$. Then $Fv=0$ and there exists $X \in \mathbb{K^n}$ such that $v=FX$. Thus, $F^2 X=0 \implies X \in Ker(F^2)$ and $X \notin Ker(F)$. We also have that $$\dim(Ker(F))=\dim(Ker(F^2))$$
since $F$ and $F^2$ have same size and rank. Thus there exist $Y \in \mathbb{K^n}$ such that $Y \in Ker(F)$ and $Y \notin Ker(F^2)$, which is a contradiction since $FY=0 \implies F^2 Y=F 0 = 0 \implies Y \in Ker(F^2)$.

Comment: Your proof is correct.  It is possible to write your argument a little more compactly -- you don't need to use matrices, for instance -- but this is a pretty good proof overall.